# Is there an Event after reordering the TreeGrid of smartclient?

Tags: javascript, drag, smartclient, treegrid

I'm using isomophics smartclient.

I have a DataBound TreeGird with drag and drop functionality. If I reorder my nodes the changes are send to the Server.

Where do I have to hook into to do something after the server response? If the reorder was Ok I have to refresh some other views.

Thanks